# Java on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, java

Is it possible to get the latest Java (Java 7u3 or Java 6u31) on FreeBSD? Everything i found on the internet is outdated. I currently have 6u24 from the packagemanager which works for now but may get problematic really soon.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but there is no Oracle (ex: Sun) java support for FreeBSD.

On the other side, you can use the [FreeBSD port of OpenJDK](http://www.freebsd.org/java/).